# Is there a Safari plugin to remove mackeeper ads?

Tags: mac, safari

I don't mind ads, banners and the like.

What I do mind is the fact that almost all the ads I see recently are ads for Mackeeper. Popups, banners, it's everywhere.

Am I the only one that has this problem?

I've recently installed AdBlock 2.5.13 to take care of the popups, yet the banners remain.

These banners state stuff as: "is your Mac slow? Use mackeeper to make it 21% faster!" I'm really getting frustrated, because:

1. my Mac is lightning fast,
2. I've tried Mackeeper on my friend's Mac, and it really is a textbook example of a bad Mac citizen. I really dislike the app (just an opinion).
3. I'm not going to buy an app to make my Mac faster, because I know there is no such thing.

Perhaps this is a google ads problem?

Comment: Which "adblocker", specifically, are you using, and on which Web browser?

Comment: AdBlock 2.5.13 on safari.

Comment: Mackeeper ads must be the most annoying in recent times. Do they really get more business that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you understand how to use the customization features in AdBlock to detect a specific ad and configure AdBlock to block it?

[Here are the AdBlock instructions](https://adblock.tenderapp.com/kb/im-seeing-an-ad/how-do-i-block-an-ad).

Comment: no I didn't! I'm checking it out now!

Answer (score 2):

they probably "target" you and you can remove it easily remove it 
form here 
https://www.google.com/settings/ads/onweb/ 
(hit the opt out link)

and here
http://www.networkadvertising.org/
(click the opt out red button)

Comment: The opt out didn't work. That annoying MacKeeper ad just keeps coming and coming.

Answer (score 0):

I see that many people have also tested mackeeper and have now very outrageous safari plugins from this site. I use now Ghostery and now bye bye mackeeper.
Never use or test mackeeper or other software from this site !!!

Comment: Your recommendation on MacKeeper might carry more weight if you explained _why_ you feel one should never use it or what site is "this site"

Comment: this site full of crapware is mackeeper.zeobit.com/‎

Answer (score 0):

It's a '**DownLite**' trojan files distributed on illegal websites that traffic in pirated movies. Remove it as follows.

**STEP 1:-** Drag the following item to the Trash. You may be prompted for your administrator login password.

/Library/LaunchAgents/com.vsearch.agent.plist

**STEP 2:-** Repeat above process with each of these lines

/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vsearch.daemon.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vsearch.helper.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/Jack.plist

**STEP 3:-** Restart the computer and empty the Trash. Then delete the following items in the same way. Some of these items may be absent.

/Library/Application Support/VSearch
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/Jack
/System/Library/Frameworks/VSearch.framework

**STEP 4:-** From the Safari menu bar, select

Safari ▹ Preferences... ▹ Extensionsu
Uninstall any extensions you don't know you need, Including ‘Spigot’. If in doubt, Uninstall all extensions. Repeat with other browsers if you have.

Again restart the computer and empty the Trash. Enjoy safe browsing.

Comment: What trojan? the OP is just asking about web adverts

Comment: It's kind of "DownLite"

Answer (score -4):

[Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/download) extension gives you

> Full detection of tracker scripts, img tags, and iframes from over 1000 data collection services

and is available for all major browsers.